# Java version does not change on Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I've installed Java 17 on my Ubuntu, it is in the usr/lib/jvm folder, and I can use it in e.g. Intellij IDEA, but when I check the Java version with 'java -version' or 'javac -version', it still returns 'openjdk version 11.0.14'. And Java 17 is not visible when I tried to change to it in 'sudo update-alternatives --config java'. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It probably in your PATH environment variable there is a path to your old java installation. Update your PATH to have the path to your new java installation to be at least before the old one or better yet remove the path to the old version from your PATH. to check that this IS your problem invoke your new 'java' command with full path:

```
/path/to/java17/bin/java -version
```

And see that you will see version 17. If so then it is most likely your PATH still pointing to the old version that is the cause of your problem

Comment: *I've installed Java 17 on my Ubuntu* You installed it with the package manager?

Comment: And how can I do that? Because I tried it several ways to updat my PATH, but neither of them worked.

Comment: Look here: https://mkyong.com/linux/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu/